# Printing Class information C# Forms

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to make a program which stores a bunch of country information from a country class in an AVL tree. I am using a form which prints out the list of countries which is saved in a CSV file and when I click on a country I want the program to print out information which corresponds to the selected country.

The problem I am having is getting it to print out the GDP in a text box when I select a country in the list box.

What code can I put to into list box which will print the gdp into a textbox?

```
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Country country = (Country)listBox1.SelectedValue;

        }
```

.

```
namespace country
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AVLTree<Country> myTree = new AVLTree<Country>();
       List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>();

        static string[] headers = new string[6];
        string buffer = "";



        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

            const int MAX_LINES_FILE = 50000;
            string[] AllLines = new string[MAX_LINES_FILE];

            AllLines = File.ReadAllLines("countries.CSV");

            foreach (string line in AllLines)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("Country"))
                {
                    headers = line.Split(',');
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] columns = line.Split(',');


                    LinkedList<string> tradePartner = new LinkedList<string>();
                    string[] partners = columns[5].Split(';', '[', ']');


                    foreach (string x in partners)
                    {
                        if (x != "")
                        {

                            tradePartner.AddLast(x);
                        }
                    }

                    myTree.InsertItem(new Country(columns[0], float.Parse(columns[1]), float.Parse(columns[2]), float.Parse(columns[3]), float.Parse(columns[4]), tradePartner));


                }
            }
            myTree.PreOrder(ref buffer);
            Console.WriteLine("Tree Contains " + buffer);



            Add();

        }

        private void Add()
        {

            myTree.CInOrder(ref Countries);
            foreach (Country y in Countries)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(y.Countryname);

            }

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Country country = (Country)listBox1.SelectedValue;

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

country class

```
    public Country (string cn, float gd, float i, float tb, float hd, LinkedList<string> mt)
    {
        this.Countryname = cn;
        this.gdp = gd;
        this.inflation = i;
        this.tradeBalance = tb;
        this.hdi = hd;
        this.mtp = mt;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        Country temp = (Country)other;
        return Countryname.CompareTo(temp.Countryname);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        foreach (string i in mtp)
            x += i + ",";
        return Countryname + " " + gdp + " " + inflation + " " + tradeBalance +" " + hdi + " " + x;


    }





}
```

Comment: Is all of this code needed to explain your problem?

Comment: probably not no but the more the better?

Comment: Definitely no - minimal is better. There is special close vote reason for cases when OP does not find it useful to provide [MCVE]...

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Country country = (Country)listBox1.SelectedValue;
        if (country != null ) 
           textBox1.Text = country.gdp;
    }
```

Comment: I entered something along them lines but I keep getting an error ' inaccessible due to its protection level'

Comment: make the variable public (the gdp)